# Exam package labels multiply defined

Tags: exam

I am using the exam package to create a questionnaire.
I have two sections with multiple choice questions.
When I put two "questions" environment under each sections, I get latex warning mentioning labels defined multiple times (Label `question@1' multiply defined etc).
Does anyone know how to avoid having two questions with same label?
A sample code is given below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\section{On part one}

\begin{questions}

\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question 
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}


\end{questions}

\section{On part two}

\begin{questions}

\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question 
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do its business, the `exam` class uses self-defined labels, but in doing so it doesn't take into account the fact that question numbers are reset at every `questions` environment. Actually, the class seems to be expecting just *one* `questions` environment.

Using two will most certainly confuse the point system. If you don't plan to use it, you can do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\questions}
  {question@\arabic{question}}
  {question@\arabic{section}@\arabic{question}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{On part one}

\begin{questions}
\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\section{On part two}

\begin{questions}
\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The alternative is to use `\section` *inside* the single `questions` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\section{On part one}
\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}

\section{On part two}

\question
Which of the following statements is/are True?
\begin{choices}
  \choice B is true 
  \choice A is false
  \correctchoice C is false
\end{choices}

\question
Why is this false
\begin{choices}
  \correctchoice  Yay
  \correctchoice  Bee
  \correctchoice  See
  \choice  Dee
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And also very quickly, use `\fullwidth{\section{On part two}}` if you want the section name to be aligned with the left margin

Comment: The first solution does suppress the warnings (thanks !) but, as stated, the point system is lost. [examdoc.pdf](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) section 9.1: "To use this feature ...  there must be only one `questions` environment in the entire exam". For the second solution (`section` inside `questions` env), sections are indented (unless put in a `\fullwidth{}`), and the question counter is not reset.